# OClickItem of twitter listViwe Fabric Kit

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I'm Using Fabric kit of twitter to my android app , and I have a listview of tweets but whene I try to click on a tweet (item) to open a new activity ( that's shows the details of the tweet) but whene I click to the item , an app chooser apear automatically
It seems that the twitter-api already set an onItemClickListener so I'm asking if someone had already use Fabric kit I need help

```
ListView tweetLV = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list_tweets);
adapter = new TweetViewAdapter<CompactTweetView>(getActivity());
tweetLV.setAdapter(adapter);

tweetLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String hashtag = adapter.getItem(i);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, hashtag);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Any change you found an answer to this? I am in the same boat

Comment: I looked into the code and I found out that in BaseViewTweet class they are firing an intent         Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", this.getPermalinkUri()); Therefore we can change it by extending and overriding the method.

Comment: Add an intent filter for **android.intent.action.VIEW** with android:scheme="https" and you will be to catch the intent being fired. But still I would prefer a way to override the onCLickListener.

Comment: @sahu A few days ago I asked something, but I can override the method. Is there any way to eliminate this action Intent intent = new Intent ("android.intent.action.VIEW"? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933868/can-i-set-custom-onclick-on-my-timeline -using-fabric-sdk)

Comment: @pgutierrez there is a private method named SetPermaLinkLauncher in BaseTweetView class where this intent firing action is being set. Now since it is private I can't think of any way to override this method. Btw how did you override onClickListener? On overriding it I didn't get any change in behaviour. I still got the app chooser menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggest on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933868/can-i-set-custom-onclick-on-my-timeline-using-fabric-sdk) you can try to create a custom adapter that overrides the default onClick behavior of tweet:

```
class CustomTweetTimelineListAdapter extends TweetTimelineListAdapter {

    public CustomTweetTimelineListAdapter(Context context, Timeline<Tweet> timeline) {
        super(context, timeline);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //disable subviews to avoid links are clickable
        if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
            disableViewAndSubViews((ViewGroup) view);
        }

        //enable root view and attach custom listener
        view.setEnabled(true);            
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO: implement your custom behavior when clicks
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    // see full example to find helper method disableViewAndSubViews

}
```

Full code example [here](https://gist.github.com/sabadow/a7dd2575325b676a113e)

Hope it helps.